# Is it possible to remove dates from the previous and next month in bootstrap daterangepicker?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to remove all dates with class off, without losing calendar template.

This is code:

```
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 plr-16">
        <div class='input-group date' >
             <input type='text' name="daterange" placeholder="START DATE & TIME" class="form-control" />
             <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is jQuery code:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense just to disable them? Not a lot of detail in your question as to what you want to accomplish

Comment: I don't want to see those days on the calendar, but when I display none, layout breaks. So I need a better solution to hide those days.

Comment: try changing css visibility then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only hide previous and next month dates from the calendar without break layout you can apply the following `css`

```
td.off.available {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

See fiddle for this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/r5hz9b72/6/

Comment: I don't want to see days from Januar in February calendar. Display none on elements with off class is not working because of that break layout of the table.

Comment: Alright, So you can use `visibility: hidden;` for the class `td.off.available` ... I`ve edited my answer as well...